# what are these telemetry Modules in applicationinsights.config and when to use them?

Tags: azure-application-insights

Our web app runs as an azure web app (.net framework 4.8) and we use application insights to generate some performance reports and alert us when exception happens.

Looking at the applicationinsights.config, I am not sure all these modules added in are useful for us (as our site runs as azure app service).
Here is a list:

1. DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule  Needed
2. PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule   Not needed (we can check web app to see these counters if needed).
3. PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule Not sure what is the purpose
4. WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule Not needed (as this seems for windows server and we are a web app)??
5. WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule Not needed (as this seems for windows server and we are a web app)??
6. RequestTrackingTelemetryModule  needed
7. AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule   needed
8. AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule  needed

Am I right? If I am, think I want to remove these modules from the config.

Answer (score 0):

***Configuring Application Insights :***

[image]

- When we configure Application Insights in our WebApp , ***ApplicationInsights.config*** is created and the mentioned packages are added by default.

[image]

- If we configure Application Insights manually, we need to add `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` package , the below packages are added by default
  [image]
- Each Telemetry Module gathers a certain kind of data and sends it using the core API.

***QuickPulseTelemetryModule*** is used to collect Live Metrics and monitor your WebApp which is in Production.

***WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule*** is for tracking the unhandled Exceptions

***WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule*** monitors unnoticed task exceptions

- Yes, you can remove the packages if it is not required as even you can add and check them from the Portal

Ex:  PerfCounterCollector

References taken from [ApplicationInsights.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config)

Comment: I don't think copy and paste some doc is the right answer.  According to a couple of sentences in the doc WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule or UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule is for .net console, windows services etc

Comment: As per your question, yes you can remove the packages which you are not using currently.